# Simulating "this" pointer concept in friend function c++

Tags: c++

1. I have friend function 'fun()' of a class A. fun takes reference of object of type A. let's say objname is 'obj'
2. Inside fun() friend function, in order to access elements of class A, obj.member is required. Because there are large number of members i want to skip this 'obj.member' and saying 'member' should refer to the object passed.

Is there a way by which this can be achieved? say declaring something on the top of the function because of which i need not say 'obj.something' again and again, and only 'something' will be fine.

My sample code is below.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    private:
        int x;
        char c;
        string s;

    public:
    A(int x, char c, string s) : x(x), c(c), s(s){};
    friend void fun(A& obj);

};

void fun(A &obj){

    //is there any thing here i can use on top so that i don't need to refer obj.x or obj.c or obj.s ...so on?
    // anything like "using" ... which can tell which ?
    //In that way i want to similulate hidden this pointer concept.
    int x = obj.x;

    char c = obj.c;

    string s = obj.s;

    //.....similarly accessing other elements of obj 

    cout<<x<<" "<<c<<" "<<s<<" "<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    A obj(20,'Z',"friend");
    fun(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Because there are large number of members i want to skip this 'obj.member' and saying 'member'*" What does it matter how many members are in the type? That doesn't slow C++ down any when it goes to figure out where `member` is.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't - or the things that seem to work for this are really bad ideas.

In a friend (or any non-member) function, all references to an object (accessing data members, calling non-static member functions) require using the `obj.<whatever>` syntax.

Really, your question reflects a sense of false economy - sort of like Nero fiddling on the roof while most of Rome burned down.   The additional typing of `obj.` on a few statements is insignificant, and techniques to reduce the typing burden make your code less clear, harder to understand, and more confusing for future developers - including, more than likely, yourself.

You could try doing something with a macro

```
 #define X obj.

 char c = X c;
```

but that doesn't save on typing, and gives code that will be confusing to humble C++ programmers (including yourself in future).  So it is not a good idea.

You could also try doing something like

```
 void fun(A &obj)
 {
      obj.fun();    // call a member function that does everything needed
 }
```

but that is sort of pointless in practice - it is still necessary to define the member function and, if you have it, there is little need for the non-member version.

Comment: thanks! . What my basic problem was that there are two clasess A and B, both are separately inherited from some library base class. A and B has a a same name function which has exactly same code. I want to somehow write a single function for both A and B, which i was trying to achieve through friend function (or template friend), and passing object type of either A or B. But in that case i have to do 'obj.' at so many places. Is there any way you can think of?

Comment: Refactor.   Place the member function of concern (and any data members it needs to access, which are presumably also the same in the two classes) into a base class, and derive both A and B from it.

Comment: data members which I am trying to access are of Library Base Class(permission is not there to edit library class). So as per your reply and being data of library base class, i need to create a local Base class and derive it from Library Base. And then derive A and B from local base class. Am i right?